# C# button animation

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a simple two button:

- button1
- button2

i want when click on button1 the button2 start a move to right,
i write this code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 100;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Left += 20;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        //timer1.Interval = 0;

    }
```

i want when the button exit on my form border on right side,timer has stop the animation.

Comment: WInForms? WPF? WebForms? Without knowing the kind of application we can't really help.

Comment: What is exact problem?

Comment: @Richard hi richard,i write in win form

Comment: @Reniuz i want when button move to right and when complete exit on right side,timer stop.

Comment: You already wrote what you want, but what is the problem with current code? What does it do? What it does not?

Comment: @Reniuz my stop event write on button3 but i want auto stop when button2 exit from form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 100;
    //start the timer
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Left += 20;
    //check position of button. When it is outside the width of form stop the timer.
    if(button1.Left >= this.Width) 
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```